# Uninitialized Constant Mysql2 - Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

Here's my system specs:
Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit
Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.1
MySQL 5.5

I have created a new rails app using compass and when I do:

```
rake db:create --trace
```

I get the following results:

```
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mysql2
```

I can confirm that MySQL is running as I can access it from the command line. I also have the mysql2 0.3.7 gem installed. The bundle install also runs without a hitch. I've read that reverting back to MySQL 5.1 might fix the issue, but it took me so long just to get the gem installed I don't know if I want to go through that whole process again.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: what does your config/database.yml file look like?  Could be a typo in your `adapter:` line.  The capitalization of `Mysql2` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Here's my database.yml:

http://pastie.org/2618529

Comment: ok, well, that looks fine then.  Looks like maybe using an older version of the gem?

Comment: I could try reverting the mysql gem I have installed. I'll try that and post back with results.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out I downloaded the wrong MySQL package when I was trying to specify the --with-mysql-dir options.

Comment: @justin.chmura This is just a friendly advice, I am not interested in debating. I will suggest you to move to ubuntu/Mac for ruby on rails development. On windows there will be certain unwanted issues when you work on complex projects which need more and more external plugins etc. Again Its just a friendly advice nothing specific.

Comment: @MohitJain No, I totally agree. My Linux box for main Ruby development is currently in storage so I cannot use it. I'm just bare-bonesing some apps to do some proof of concepts. Getting Ruby on Rails to work on Windows has been a real pain.